# Ordenar lista do firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, realtime-database, google-storage

Atualmente eu uso essa função para ler os dados do banco firebase:

```
function ler() {
    database.ref(referencia_database).orderByChild('nome').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var chave = childSnapshot.key
            var obj = childSnapshot.val()

            //Verifica se a imagem existe no storage, se sim usa ela, se não usa a padrão
            storage.ref(chave).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                mostrar(chave, obj.nome, url)
            }).catch(function(error) {
                mostrar(chave, obj.nome, './image/default.png')
            });
        })
    })
}
```

O problema: por causa do trecho de verificação se a imagem existe ou não no storage (assíncrono), os dados são mostrados de forma aleatória.

Como solucionar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minha recomendação é: guarde o downloadURL da imagem no banco quando você guarda a imagem no Storage. Assim o seu objecto seria, por exemplo:

```
"exemploObj":{
    "nome":"nomeAqui",
    "url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/..."
    //... Talvez você tenha outros dados aqui ...
}
```

E então você não precisa mais pegar o downloadURL do storage. Só tem de pegar do banco mesmo:

```
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var chave = childSnapshot.key
            var obj = childSnapshot.val()

            //Verifica se a imagem existe no banco, se sim usa ela, se não usa a padrão
            if(childSnapshot.child('url').exists())
                mostrar(chave, obj.nome, obj.url)
            else
                mostrar(chave, obj.nome, './image/default.png')
        })
```

---

Para simplificar ainda mais o código, você pode salvar o caminho da imagem padrão no banco (ao invés de deixar esse campo vazio):

```
"exemploObj":{
    "nome":"nomeAqui",
    "url":"./image/default.png"
    //... Talvez você tenha outros dados aqui ...
}
```

E então pode tirar o `if`:

```
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var chave = childSnapshot.key
            var obj = childSnapshot.val()
            mostrar(chave, obj.nome, obj.url)
        })
```

Comment: Eu não guardo nada da imagem no banco (realtime database), pego a imagem pelo nome do arquivo que é o mesmo da chave do objeto, é melhor mudar para como você mostrou?

Comment: Sim, essa é a minha sugestão.

Comment: Ok, mas eu quero que apenas uma imagem esteja cadastrada para cada objeto, e vou organizar o storage assim: `/chave/nome_receita.png`, sabe me dizer como posso apagar as imagens de um diretório e setar outra, independente do nome, já que o usuário pode trocar a imagem e o nome do arquivo provavelmente será diferente